Opening Google-Chrome browser session in RobotFramework 7 is taking 5 mins which is too long
Opening Chrome browser session in RobotFramework 7 is taking 5 mins, So, we need to find the issue in this keyword and optimize it as ideally it should take a few seconds to open the URL in Browser.
i have tried with multiple versions of Chrome and Chromedriver and the compability is fine, as it works in RF version 3.
Irrespective of the chrome versions and irrespective of the VM, seeing this issue.
Below is the keyword snippet


${OPEN URL IN BROWSER TIMEOUT}     60s     #Time out value needed in order for a link to open in browser
${OPEN URL IN BROWSER INTERVAL}     15s     #Time interval needed in order for a link to open in browser
.......
.......
Open URL In Browser
    [Arguments]    ${url}    ${browser}    ${headless flag}=False
    ${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Run Keyword If    '${headless flag}' == 'True'    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    disable-gpu
    ${chrome_version}    Run    google-chrome --version | awk '{print$5}'     
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --user-agent\=Chrome/${chrome_version} System/ComputerId
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    start-maximized
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --window-size\=1920,1080
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --incognito
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --test-type
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --no-sandbox
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --ignore-certificate-errors
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}   add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage
    ${options}=     Call Method     ${chrome_options}    to_capabilities
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds   ${OPEN URL IN BROWSER TIMEOUT}     ${OPEN URL IN BROWSER INTERVAL}   Open Browser    ${url}    browser=${browser}     options=${chrome_options} 

Robot debug LOG:
2024-06-20 11:25:09.079157 - INFO - +---- START KEYWORD: BuiltIn.Wait Until Keyword Succeeds [ ${OPEN URL IN BROWSER TIMEOUT} | ${OPEN URL IN BROWSER INTERVAL} | Open Browser | ${url} | browser=${browser} | options=${chrome_options} ]
2024-06-20 11:25:09.079892 - INFO - +----- START KEYWORD: SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser [ ${url} | browser=${browser} | options=${chrome_options} ]
2024-06-20 11:25:09.080411 - DEBUG - Test timeout 30 minutes active. 1783.012 seconds left.
2024-06-20 **11:25:09.080732 **- INFO - Opening browser 'Chrome' to base url 'https://100.78.142.56:30008'.
2024-06-20 11:30:11.059438 - DEBUG - Opened browser with session id 9ca994124566f2cf5094ea9bc3d385d4.
2024-06-20 11:30:11.059871 - INFO - +----- END KEYWORD: SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser (301.979979 s)
2024-06-20 11:30:11.060113 - INFO - +---- END KEYWORD: BuiltIn.Wait Until Keyword Succeeds (301.980956 s)
2024-06-20 11:30:11.060332 - INFO - +--- END KEYWORD: testkeywords.Open URL In Browser (302.035011 s)


Time taken to execute this keyword is always 5 mins - 11:30-11:25


Can anyone please help identify and fix this issue in RobotFramework 7 (Python 3.12.2) ?
Tried with below versions:
$ python3 -c "import selenium; print(selenium.version)"
4.21.0

$ **chromedriver **--version
ChromeDriver 103.0.5060.134 (8ec6fce403b3feb0869b0732eda8bd95011d333c-refs/branch-heads/5060@{#1262})
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 103.0.5060.114

2.# **chromedriver **--version
ChromeDriver 125.0.6422.141 (4b1e83937122185343ba92e909b021f307c719ca-refs/branch-heads/6422@{#1186})
#google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 125.0.6422.141



ChromeDriver Version: 124.0.6367.8




Google Chrome Version: 124.0.6367.8


Check whether there is a problem with the options passed. Have you tried to run the 'Open browser' keyword without options? For example,  'Open Browser    ${url}    browser=${browser}' and 'Open Browser   browser=${browser}'

yes @SamMaksymyshyn, i tried running without passing 'options', still its taking 5mins to respond whether its able to open browser or not
14:19:02.991293 - INFO - +---- START KEYWORD: BuiltIn.Wait Until Keyword Succeeds [ ${OPEN URL IN BROWSER TIMEOUT} | ${OPEN URL IN BROWSER INTERVAL} | Open Browser | ${url} | browser=${browser} ]
14:19:02.992021 - INFO - +----- START KEYWORD: SeleniumLibrary.Open Browser [ ${url} | browser=${browser} ]
14:19:02.992712 - INFO - Opening browser 'Chrome' to base url xx
2024-06-20 14:24:03.252665 - INFO - Cannot capture screenshot because no browser is open.

Thank you for trying! hmm, then it is not clear to me what happening. Just in case, why are you using Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  ... before 'Open Browser ..'? You could generally use 'Open browser' without any special keyword.
